# Получить содержимое буфера обмена (современным образом)

Tags: javascript

Приветствую всех.
Необходимо получить содержимое буфера обмена, но я столкнулся с кое-какой проблемой.
Прежде всего, хочу подчеркнуть тот факт, что мне нужно получить данные из буфера современным макаром, а это значить использовать "clipboard API and EVENTS"

```js
//Вешаем событие onpaste, котороя срабатывает при вставке текстовых данные в поле input
input.addEventListener("paste", function(e)
{
  // Собственно, выводим данные из буфера в консоль
  console.log(e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain"));

  // Таким образом я легко получаю содержимое буфера
  // но проблема в том, что в спецификации указано, что
  //методы getData, setData, clearData устаревшие, а аналогов я не встретил.


  // Т.к. вышеуказанные методы считаются устаревшими, каким образом
  //я могу получать данные из буфера и записывать их туда?
  //Имеется ли замена устаревшим методам?
});
```

Comment: На хабре прошла информация , что такое будет возможно только в хроме 43....

Comment: То-есть, на данный момент, придется пользоваться устаревшими методами?

Comment: на данный момент ничего подобного мне неудалось найти.

Comment: Почему я не родился через лет 20, чтобы уже все стабильно было((((